# Hide admin tool bar from back end dashboard

Tags: admin-bar

How do we hide the admin toolbar from the back end dashboard?

We can hide the toolbar when viewing the website with the below code but we want to also hide it from back end?

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WordPress page for](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/show_admin_bar) `show_admin_bar` says:

> You cannot turn off the toolbar on the WordPress dashboard

However, this trick works

```
    function remove_admin_bar() { ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin-top: -28px;
        }

        body.admin-bar #wphead {
            padding-top: 0;
        }

        #wpadminbar {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
<?php }

add_action( 'admin_head', 'remove_admin_bar' );
```

In oreder to remove certain menus from admin bar use `$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu($id);` where `$id` of a specific menu can be found in Chrome Dev Tool. Each menus' `<li>` id in Dev tool is in the form of `wp-admin-bar-{id}`, for example Comments menu has id `wp-admin-bar-comments`. So to remove this menu code should be like this,

```
// remove links/menus from the admin bar
function my_admin_bar_render() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('comments');
    // Code to remove other items goes here
    ....
    ....
}
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'my_admin_bar_render' );
```

Comment: Hi Qaisar Feroz, this works but then we cant log out, is there anyway to hide everything and just just keep the login user settings with the logout link? Thank you

Comment: Answer updated, see the last code block as a guide.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Turn Off the Admin Toolbar in Settings***. Disable the admin toolbar in your profile settings. To remove the toolbar from your site, go to **Users > Your Profile**. Scroll down to “Toolbar” and check “**Show Toolbar when viewing site.**”

***Reference :*** https://www.machothemes.com/blog/disable-wordpress-admin-bar/